# How to sniff Oracle's credentials from a connection attempt to the database?

Tags: oracle, odbc, legacy, sniffing

I have a legacy application, which connects to the configured Oracle database.

It seems it has some logic that alters the database credentials as it is unable to successfully log in to the Oracle database, while `sqlplus` started on the same machine is able to log in.

The error I am getting is: `[DataDirect][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

How to find out what is the database username and password that are sent to the database?

What I have tried so far:

1. Enabled auditing of failed sign-on attempts on Oracle (`audit create session whenever not successful`). It does not solve the issue, because it only logs the username, which seems to be correct, without the password.
2. Used a sniffer to eavesdrop the network traffic between the machine running the application and the database, but since Oracle's TNS protocol is encrypted, it did not help a lot.
3. Started a server using `netcat` on port X, provided port X in the application configuration file. The application did connect to my server, that is how I know the application is connecting to the correct server. But since the TNS protocol is pretty complex (requires a series of messages to be exchanged between the client and the server) I hope there is a simpler why of achiving what I want without having to reverse engineer Oracle and implementing my own server.
4. Enabled tracing of the JDBC driver (`Trace=1`, `TraceFile`, `TraceDll`). The trace file shows the correct username, but obviously the password is not getting logged.

My environment:

- Database: Oracle 11g
- Application runs on: Solaris
- Application uses: DataDirect ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol v70

Comment: You just want to know the password it's providing so you can change the username password in the DB?

Comment: @FelipeMoreno I do not want to change the password, I want the application to be able to connect to the database.

Comment: You probably can't log the actual password that is sent.  It would be a security issue if you could.  I don't even believe that a client-side SQL*Net trace would reveal that information.  Are you sure that the issue is with the password and that the application is manipulating the password you're providing?  What is the error that you are getting?  Have you enabled case-sensitive passwords on your 11g database?  If this is a legacy application, it may have been written to assume that passwords were case-inssnsitive.

Comment: the app alters the credentials?  You probably "think" the app is using credentials X, but its really reading a different cfg file or similar and passing in credentials Y (or a firewall issue maybe).  Can you step through a debugger with this app?  What language?

Comment: @tbone Yes, I think the application alters the credentials, because 1)  I was able to get the application to connect to my server so the config file is correct, 2) there are failed sign-on attempts logged in Oracle confirming the application is able to connect to the database. Can I use a debugger? I wanted to make sure that there is no well-known solution to such problem prior starting debugging. Now it seems that debugging is the best available option.

Comment: @JustinCave I have not mentioned this, but I have access to the root account on the machine running the application, what gives me a whole bunch of options how to progress with this investigation, using `truss` and `dtrace` being one of the first that come to my mind. I have added the error message to the question.

Comment: Did you enable case-sensitive passwords in your database?  Does the legacy app support case-sensitive passwords?  Or does it expect passwords to be case insensitive?

Comment: @JustinCave I do not know the app restrictions, but Oracle's audit log contained exactly the same username as provided in the config file, ok, maybe the password is handled differently, I can try in a few hours and come back here.

Comment: Usually "legacy app" is code for "some old app written years ago that works so we leave it alone (and secretly scared to mess with it)".  I feel your pain, but you need to setup a test environment where you can step through the code.  Even if you figure this problem out, there will be others eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure, but if connection established by ODBC  driver (as described in question tags) then you can try ODBC sniffing tools like [ODBC Tracing](http://www.mcpressonline.com/application-software/microsoft/microsoft-computing-odbc-security.html).

Citation:

**Password "Sniffing" Using Trace**

ODBC provides a means for tracing the conversation taking place between the driver and the host database. Used by developers for testing purposes, the tracing feature is designed to help programmers find out exactly what is going on and to help fix problems. However, tracing (also called "sniffing") can be used by nefarious bad guys to retrieve user passwords.

When tracing is enabled, communications with the host are written to a file. This includes the user ID and password, which are captured in plain text.

**Update**

SQLPlus connects to Oracle with OCI interface, but DataDirect ODBC driver uses it's own proprietary implementation of communication protocol. So, most probable point of failure is driver misconfiguration or incompatibility.

DataDirect provides some [tools](http://www.datadirect.com/support/downloads/tools.html) for ODBC drivers diagnostics, but only option applicable to case described in question is using [`snoop`](http://www.datadirect.com/resources/odbc/troubleshoot-odbc-driver/diagnostic.html#ivtestlib) utility, which acts like a `netcat` which already tried.

Because connection failed at credential verification stage, the most probable source of error is using localized symbols for user name or password. There are some issues with Oracle authentication process, listed in DataDirect [Knowledge Search](http://knowledgebase.datadirect.com/KnowledgeSearch) (search for `ORA-01017`).

It seems that DataDirect provides two separate version of driver with and without Unicode support, therefore one of possible points of failure is to connecting with non-Unicode version of driver to Unicode version of database and vice verse.

P.S. For now I don't have any experience with DataDirect ODBC driver. So it's only suggestions about possible source of failure.

Comment: The connection is established by an ODBC driver but running on Solaris, so I think this Windows-specific ODBC tracing cannot be used.